# Some Postscript Specials could not be rendered - why?

Tags: includegraphics, postscript

The following code throws an error:

```
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\singlespacing

\chapter{Linear Transformations}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering

\includegraphics{vector1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The following code does not:

```
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\singlespacing

\chapter{Linear Transformations}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering

\includegraphics{vector1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

There are no issues with my eps files. Everything works perfectly. When I try to put an image on the first page of a chapter, it throws the error. Why?

Comment: Without access to the actual image, without knowing what engine (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) it is probably hard to tell

Comment: @KenM, can you please complete your code (MWE)? E.g. which calss do you use, which packages do you include AND still obtain said error ... Thanks

Comment: you have not provided any code that anyone can debug. The most common reason to get a warning abouyt PS specials is to use a package such as pstricks or use the dvips option for graphicx, both of which need latex+dvips, but use pdflatex.

Comment: Hi folks - what code would you like me to include.  The code snippet above works perfectly if I am attempting to display the image on the second page of a chapter. For some reason, it will not display on the first page, and I get the postscript specials error. It is very strange. I have confirmed there is no issue with the ps file. I used potrace to convert from a bmp to an eps file. Every other image displays perfectly anywhere in the file, except on the first page of a chapter. I tried changing from document class report to document class book, but it did not help.

Comment: btw I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.2)

Comment: you have not shown any code that would generate postscript specials. do not pputr code in comments, you can edit the question to add a code block that produces the warning that you are asking about

Comment: pdflatex can not include eps files, only by calling out to epstopdf to convert then top pdf files which it can include, but that processes does not involve `\special`

Comment: Folks - I think the question I am asking is not being addressed. To clarify: Yes I am using eps files, because that is the default output from potrace. Yes, eps files work perfectly for anything I have written so far. The issue is that if I try to display an image on the first page of a chapter, then it throws an error. If I put a \newpage before the code snippet from above, then the image displays perfectly. There are no issues with my eps files.